# Want to make a padded color line across a page

Tags: css

I want to make a line lets say green padded about 20px across a page. what html or css to do this?

I have tried a simple code that I found on the other website but no success.
What I specifically want it to just have a line going across a page, as this would be used as an additional background to an image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not just use an `<hr>` element and style it accordingly?

**HTML**

```
<p>some content</p>
<hr class="line">
<p>some more content</p>
```

**CSS**

```
.line {
    height:20px;
    background-color: green;
    border:0;
}
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/uVn8J/)